# Java - Test if Random queue is periodic

Tags: java, random, queue

OK, I have been digging through the www but haven't found a solution to my problem. I will try to explain as best as I can. Please excuse my bad english ;)

I have to create a queue using the class Random. I know this class is only "pseudorandom" but that doesn't matter.

Next I have to test the queue whether it is periodic or not. If it isn't periodic I can continue. I found  no algorithm to test the queue on that, and it seems to be rather complicated creating my own. Has anybody of you ever created something similiar or can give me some advice how I can achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: `return true`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Periodicity

Comment: I know this. The seed is changing every time I create the queue. My task includes that I test if the queue is periodic at some point.

Comment: Ah, homework, how I don't miss you.  Being honest with you, this website is dedicated to solving problems with definitive answers put forward by users who either have put in demonstrable effort to try and solve their problem, or are able to display the problem in concrete form (IE: MCVE).  This fits in neither boat.  But, to throw you a bone, I'm guessing you're looking for a cycle detection algorithm.  If you Google "cycle detection", you'll probably find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the queue, until you find an element which is equal to the first element of the queue. Compare subsequent elements while `i < length && e[i] == e[(n + i) % length]`.  If `i == length`, you have periodicity. Otherwise, move on to the next `i` where `e[0] == e[i]` and repeat.

Runs in O(n^2), but should be OK for homework...

Comment: Thank you! Sadly I can't upvote your answer because I have not enough reputation yet...